# gaps in QTreeWidget AlternatingRowColors

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, stylesheet, houdini

I'm trying to add a QTreeWidget with alternating row colours to a python panel in Houdini but getting these strange gaps in the dark alternations.

Has anyone seen this problem before and know how to fix it?

[image]

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Houdini 17 here and it works fine with this code. You should post a sample of your code.

[image: alternate colored tree]

```
from hutil.Qt import QtWidgets
def onCreateInterface():
    tree = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
    tree.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

    item1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(tree, ['item1'])
    item11 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item1, ['item11'])
    item111 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item11, ['item111'])
    item1111 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item111, ['item1111'])
    item2 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(tree, ['item2'])
    item21 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item2, ['item21'])
    item211 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item21, ['item211'])
    item212 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item21, ['item212'])
    item213 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(item21, ['item213'])
    return tree
```

Comment: Hi @Regnareb,

Sorry for not posting code was in a rush when posting this.
Looks like this is a bug in Houdini 16 as I have copied your code in 16 and 17 and it only happens in 16.
I can see there are a lot of differences in the default Style Sheets, will see if I can get the fix from the 17 Style Sheet and copy it over as Houdini 17 isn't to stable on the version of Linux we are using so I'm stuck with 16 at the moment.

Thanks for your help,
Mark

Comment: try .setProperty("houdiniStyle", True) on your root widget. This fixes some UI errors sometimes for me

Comment: @G.Vernier unfortunately, that didn't seem to do anything. I might have to wait for my company changs Linux version so we can use Houdini 17